# How to store and pick images from the app itself

Tags: swift, xcode

Is it possible to create an image picker within the app?
I want to store like 100 images in the app and allow the users to pick the images from those 100 images.
Can the image picker give us both the option to pick the images from the photo library and the stored 100 images in the app?

Comment: Please, try to focus on one question and tell us what you already did.

Comment: The built in image picker only supports the camera and photo library as sources. You cannot specify your own custom images. A custom component will be needed to show your 200 images and allow the user to choose one. A collection view would seem to be a good choice. There may be third-party libraries available for this.